# ou have imported an APK or an app bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid You must sign either with a valid certificate

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, store

I am trying to publish my app on the google play store i followed all the steps in the flutter documentation but when i upload the app bundle it shows an error :
ou have imported an APK or an app bundle signed with a certificate that is not yet valid You must sign either with a valid certificate . i didnt understand what is the problem .

i tried to upload to the play store but it didnt accept the appbundle for the reason i mentionned .
i also tried to generate a certificate from another computer but it didnt work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.